# What does Euler mean when he says "Let the arc z be infinitely small ; there will be sin.z=z and cos.z=1..."?

Tags: trigonometry, math-history, binomial-theorem, trigonometric-series

I am referring to, specifically the `sin.z=z and cos.z=1`. I am reading Euler's *Introductio In Analysin Infinitorium, Vol. I, Ch. VIII* and he jumps from binomials to assuming the arc z is infinitely small. I'm not sure why he does this. Could someone help explain what he means by this part of his text and why the approximate quantities, `sin.z=z and cos.z=1`, are true?

[Here is a screenshot of the section of text I am referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLiCy.png)

Comment: When the arc becomes very small, the higher order terms become negligible

Comment: He is, if you like, describing the Taylor series expansion of these functions to first order.

Comment: It should at least be clear why $\cos z\approx 1$ when $z$ is small, no?  And one can prove with ordinary geometry that $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$.

Comment: So he's using limits without technically calculating the limits and involving small-angle approximation? Since he obtains the Taylor series (centered around 0) without doing any calculus.

Comment: The modern conception of limits dates back only to the 1820s.  Euler died in 1783.  His treatment of what we now call "limits" will look very different from ours.  He's doing calculus, but it's a version of calculus that predates limits.

Comment: Right, so would the law of sines, Fermat's arclength formula, and the double angle identity come into play here instead?